# form_for undefined method `user_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting an error :

```
undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd1f223ead0>:0x007fd1f2241af0>
```

when I'm trying to edit a student. I don't really understand the "user_path" method alert since I never write this in the view. (Student is not model) and I didn't use rails g scaffold to generate it.

Thanks

In my StudentsController :

```
def edit
  @student = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

In the view (edit.html.erb) :

```
<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %> ...
```

In routes.rb :

```
resources :students
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

you have a `students_controller` which corresponds to the `resources :students` line in your `routes.rb`.  This creates routes that uses the word `students` like `students_path` and `new_student_path`.  When using `form_for(@record)`, the url is determined from the objects class.  In this case, `@record` is a `User` so the path is `users_path` when the object is a new record and `user_path(@record)` when the object is persisted.  since you don't have a `users_controller` defined, you need to manually set the url of the `form_for` to fix this error

```
form_for @user, url: student_path(@user), html: { method: :put } do |f|
```

now, if you're using a partial called `_form.html.erb` and uses this on both the new and edit actions, you're going to have a problem since the urls for both new and edit actions are different. you have to change your views to something like this

```
# new.html.erb
form_for @user, url: students_path, html: { method: :post } do |f|
  render 'form', f: f

# edit.html.erb
form_for @user, url: student_path(@user), html: { method: :put } do |f|
  render 'form', f: f

# _form.html.erb
f.text_field :name
f.text_field :title
```

Comment: having the `form_for` outside the partial is a little icky. Would pass the method and path in as local variables

Comment: if you call `form_for` outside the partial, you only have to pass the form renderer object.  the method and path should be passed to `form_for`.  i guess the best example on when this is best used is if you have an admin side and you use the same form for the public side of your app.

Comment: what if i am not using the partial or new/edit forms, but still getting the same error

Comment: the stacktrace should point out where `user_path` is being called.  start debugging there.

Answer (score 5):

If you are here because of the namespace (like me 10 minutes ago) you'll need this:

> For namespaced routes, like admin_post_url:
>
> ```rb
> <%= form_for([:admin, @post]) do |f| %>
>  ...
> <% end %>
> ```

from the [doc](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Comment: Wowww, nice one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

i fix it with local variables in render . In rails 5  - form_with tag:

```
# new.html.erb
  render partial: 'form', locals: {user: @user, url: students_path}

# edit.html.erb
  render partial: 'form', locals: {user: @user, url: student_path(@user)}

# _form.html.erb
form_with  model: user, url: url, local: true do |f|
  f.text_field :name
  f.text_field :title
end
```