# Use or need of url: and html: with form_for - Undefined method 'xxx_path for #

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Development Environment: CentOS 6.5; Ruby 2.1.1; Rails 4.1.0.rc2
Novice RoR developer, experienced in other programming languages
Learning from/following the www.railstutorial.org online book

I am trying to figure out if and how to use the url: and html: modifiers with the "form_for" helper function. Looking at other posts, here on stackoverflow, the closest I have found and used as a reference is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740702/form-for-undefined-method-user-path).

My Controller has

```
def apply
    @applicant = Applicant.new
end
```

The view (apply.html.erb) has

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for (@applicant) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :sName, "Short Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :sName %>
```

and the routes.rb file has

```
match '/membership/apply',        to: 'membership#apply',        via: 'get'
match '/membership/submitted',    to: 'membership#submit',       via: 'post'
match '/membership/pre_approve',  to: 'membership#pre_approval', via: 'put'
match '/membership/finalize_app', to: 'membership#finalize_app', via: 'put'
match '/membership/approve',      to: 'membership#approve',      via: 'post'  
match '/membership/endorse',      to: 'membership#endorse',      via: 'put'
match '/membership/status',       to: 'membership#status',       via: 'get'
```

when I visit localhost:3000/membership/apply, I get the following error-

`undefined method 'applicants_path' for #`

and when I've tried using the url: and html: hashes -

`<%= form_for (@applicant), url: membership, html: { method: :get } do |f| %>`

I then receive the error-

`undefined local variable or method 'membership' for #`

Is this more of a routing issue with the route.rb file? Is the use of the url: and html: modifiers correct?

Comment: can you run this command --> 'rake routes' and post the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you're using `membership` for your `url` argument. `membership` (in this sense) will be treated as a local variable, and means you don't have it defined

You'll need to pass a [route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to your `url` arg:

```
<%= form_for (@applicant), url: membership_path do |f| %>
```

Secondly, are you sure you want to use `method: :get`? If you're *applying* for a position, I'm sure you'll need to `POST` the data to your server?

---

I'd do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :memberships, path_names: { new: "apply" } #-> creates /memberships/apply

#app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb
Class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @applicant = Membership.new #-> assuming you want to use your membership model?
    end
end

#app/views/memberships/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @applicant do |f| %> #-> Rails uses the ActiveRecord object to build routes for form etc
```

Comment: +1 for encouraging use of resourceful routes and correct HTTP verbs

Comment: Thanks Dave - it's the most efficient way to do it. I upvoted the other answer too!

Comment: This answer showed where I was mixed up and gave me more to see/learn. The path_names hash will do/clean up a few other things I've been working on as well.  Buck's answer (above) got me going but this one added more. Thanks for the info. btw... the 'get' was a hangover from another copy/paste. Found that after the action :-\.

Answer (score 3):

The `form_for` method applies some Rails magic to route the submitted form. Since you’re not using RESTful routes, you need to specify the endpoint, as you guessed in the second `form_for`. But `membership` isn’t the correct route helper method. Run `rake routes` as Jack suggested in the comment and you’ll find the route is called `membership_apply`, which means your `form_for` should look like this:

```
<%= form_for (@applicant), url: membership_apply_path, html: { method: :get } do |f| %>
```

(The other option is `membership_apply_url` if you want a full URL rather than just a path.)

Apart from your immediate problem: your proliferation of custom routes signals that you may need some intermediary objects that can be treated as their own resources. Or maybe you need a state machine implementation to move a `Membership` along through the process.