# undefined method `model_path' when using resource :model for routing in form_for edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are a few similar questions that exist to this, but I could not clearly understand the answer. I am trying to make a simple rails application with CRUD operations for a specific *model*. I am specifically having trouble with doing this using the *form_for* function for updating the record.

My routes.rb file:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'main#index'
  devise_for :users

  resource :models
  get 'main/index'

end
```

My models_controller.rb

```rb
class ModelsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @nc = Model.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @nc = Model.find(params[:id])
    @nc.update(model_params)
    if @nc.save
      flash[:success] = 'Changes saved.'
      redirect_to model_path
    else
      flash[:error] = @nc.errors.empty? ? 'Error' : @nc.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end

  def model_params
    params.require(:model).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
  end

end
```

and finally my model/edit.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_for @nc do |nc| %>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <form role='form'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-6'>
            <div class='form-group'>
              <%= nc.label :first_name %>
              <%= nc.text_field :first_name, :class => 'form-control', :value => @nc.first_name != nil ? @nc.first_name : '' %>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
              <%= nc.label :last_name %>
              <%= nc.text_field :last_name, :class => 'form-control', :value => @nc.last_name != nil ? @nc.last_name : '' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-12'>
            <%= nc.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %> <%= link_to 'Cancel', :back, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I actually run this and attempt to edit the model, before I can submit anything I get:

```
undefined method `model_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003cb52c0>:0x007fb7022b18b0>
Did you mean?  models_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`redirect_to model_path`

to

`redirect_to @nc`

If you run your rake routes, you'll see that `model_path` requires an id - using @nc tells rails to do what you want it to do.

Comment: I am running a development build on localhost. The error I get actually highlights "<%= form_for @nc do |nc| %>" as the issue.

[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740702/form-for-undefined-method-user-path?rq=1) issue is perhaps the closest, but I do not think it should be necessary to manually set a url in this case.

Comment: Your original post said the problem was undefined method 'model_path'.